# Right angle parallelepipeds with the same greatest diagonal (the sides and greatest diagonal positive integers with g.c.d=1)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let’s have the equation

$$(r_1\times p+p)^4-(4r_1^3+6r_1^2+4r_1+1)\times p^4=(r_1\times p)^4$$

And if $p=2$ and $r_1=n/2$  where $n$ a  positive integer  the above equation is written as follows:

$$(n+2)^4-[4(n/2)^3+6(n/2)^2+4(n/2)+1]\times2^4=n^4$$

In order to obtain formulas for Pythagorian quadruplets from this equation we set $n=[2\times(q^2+q)]$ and we have

$$[2(q^2+q+1)]^4-[64q^6+192q^5+288q^4+256q^3+160q^2+64q+16]=[2(n^2+n)]^4$$

But

$$64q^6+192q^5+288q^4+256q^3+160q^2+64q+16=[2(q+1)]^4+(8q^3+12q^2+8q)^2$$

and

$$64q^6+192q^5+288q^4+256q^3+160q^2+64q+16=(2q)^4+(8q^3+12q^2+8q+4)^2$$

After dividing by $16$ we obtain:

$$(q^2+q+1)^4=(q^2+q)^4+(q+1)^4+(2q^3+3q^2+2q)^2$$

and

$$(q^2+q+1)^4=(q^2+q)^4+q^4+(2q^3+3q^2+2q+1)^2$$

So we found two nontrivial solutions for the same greatest diagonal.

From my previous work on a different hyperelliptic equation I had found the following formula:

$$(q^2+q+1)^4=(q+1)^4+q^4+(q^4+2q^3+3q^2+2q)^2$$

If $q=2$ then we have $7^4=6^4+3^4+32^2$,  $7^4=6^4+2^4+33^2$, $7^4=3^4+2^4+48^2$

So we have three nontrivial solutions.

Does anyone know how to obtain more than three nontrivial solutions in positive integers for the same greatest diagonal?

Comment: Could you please clarify where is the parellelopiped in these equations---which variables represent its side lengths?---and which variable (presumably $q$?) represents the largest diagonal?

Comment: Are you just asking for square numbers that can be written as sums of three squares in more than three ways?

Comment: If we have $a^4=b^4+c^4+d^2$ then $a=(q^2+q+1)^2$ is the greatest diagonal. $b=(q^2+q)^2, (q+1)^2$, and so on. The other two sides derive from the above material.

Comment: The second term should be $a^2=(q^2+q+1)^2$ and the third $b^2=(q^2+q)^2,(q+1)^2$, and so on. (one of the sides of the parallelepiped).